# SweetAlert2 not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making my first simple CRUD application using Rails 5.1.5. I used scaffold to easily generate my first table.

Then, I found gem called [sweet-alert2-rails](https://github.com/nicolasblanco/sweet-alert2-rails) to have some fun with the layout. I followed the instruction in the readme file and it works pretty well... but it doesn't have any functionality. Before installing the SweetAlert, when I clicked the delete button, selected record disappeared. Now, it doesn't matter if I click "Ok" or "Cancel", there is no reaction to the record.

I tried to find a solution and I hoped that [this](http://alexzerbach.com/use-sweet-alert-rails/) would help. I copied JS code to assets/javascripts/application.js, but there's no reaction from my site.

Sorry if it's a trivial question, but it's my very first step into Rails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following, it's working on my side, copy & paste this instead of [yours](http://alexzerbach.com/use-sweet-alert-rails/)

```
//Override the default confirm dialog by rails
$.rails.allowAction = function(element){
    if( undefined === element.attr('data-confirm') ){
        return true;
    }

    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(element);
    return false;
};

//User click confirm button
$.rails.confirmed = function(element){
    element.removeAttr('data-confirm');
    element.trigger('click.rails');
};

//Display the confirmation dialog
$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(element){
    var msg = element.data('confirm');
    alertify.confirm(msg, function(e){
        if(e){
            $.rails.confirmed(element);
            return true;
        }
    })
};
```

It should work

Comment: Should I paste this into app/assets/javascripts/application.js or somewhere else? Pasting into application.js doesn't change anything - window appears, but confirming the popup window doesn't work. I also noticed that I had to install 'sweet-alert-confirm' gem - without this alert window is not even shown.

Comment: That is working on my hand, I don't know what's happening there,  yes it's paste to theapplication js

Comment: https://dev.to/peterfication/how-to-use-sweetalert2-for-your-rails-51-rails-ujs-confirms-withoutjquery-67h It fixed the problem for me. You have to load the code before rails_ujs

Comment: @chell can you write your answer here that what you did, there is lot of mixture on that link and tough to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can find references on my blog and in my GitHub repository. I have written this article for Rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.1.0. and also implemented the code for the same version.

Blog : https://rutikkpatel.medium.com/sweet-alert-2-in-ruby-on-rails-7-3f4cffe1ea5f

GitHub Repository : https://github.com/rutikkpatel/Sweet-Alert-Rails

**I hope that will help you with your issue.**